# Upload large file to ftp C#

Tags: c#, ftp

I'm uploading large files to ftp site using this code.

### Code

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(FileLoc, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string ftpUrl = string.Format("{0}/{1}", uploadUrl, uploadFileName);
                FtpWebRequest requestObj = FtpWebRequest.Create(ftpUrl) as FtpWebRequest;
                requestObj.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
                requestObj.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Uid, Pass);
                using (Stream requestStream = requestObj.GetRequestStream())
                {

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[8092];
                    int read = 0;

                    while ((read = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                    {
                        requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                    }

                    requestStream.Flush();
                    if (fs != null)
                    {
                        fs.Close();
                        fs.Dispose();
                    }
                    if (requestStream != null)
                    {
                        requestStream.Close();
                        requestStream.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Some times this code up-lode files very fine but some time it up-lodes some part of file not complete file and doesn't give any error.

Can any one help me why some time it upload only some part of file not hole file.

Comment: How big large is "large?"  Also- do you own the server where the file is being uploaded, or does some 3rd party?

Comment: file size up to 2 Gb.
And I'm using 3rd party ftp site.

Comment: Then is it possible that the 3rd party is dropping/closing the connection, or (if they're moving the file) picking it up before the file completes?

Comment: You can use the WebClient.UploadFile() convenience method instead.  That is unlikely to make any difference, you almost surely have to look for the problem on the other end of the wire.

Comment: You said that it is possible that 3rd party dropping/closing the connection but in that case it must give error but it is not giving any error.I've change buffer size `8092` to `999999` and it starts uploading fine.I think when `fs.Read` reads from a chunk that doesn't have any char at that time it terminates the reding and writing.Is there any other way to loop through end of file.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the code we use for uploading to FTP. It looks very similar to your own. Nevertheleess, I post it for your reference as we haven't had any such reported failures

```
    private void UploadFile(string fileToUpload)
    {
        Output = new Uri(Path.Combine(Output.ToString(), Path.GetFileName(fileToUpload)));
        FtpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(Output) as FtpWebRequest;
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        // in order to work with Microsoft Windows Server 2003 + IIS, we can't use passive mode.
        request.UsePassive = false;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);

        // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
        Stream dest = request.GetRequestStream();
        FileStream src = File.OpenRead(fileToUpload);

        int bufSize = (int)Math.Min(src.Length, 1024);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufSize];
        int bytesRead = 0;

        int numBuffersUploaded = 0;            

        do
        {
            bytesRead = src.Read(buffer, 0, bufSize);
            dest.Write(buffer, 0, bufSize);
            numBuffersUploaded++;
        }
        while (bytesRead != 0);

        dest.Close();
        src.Close();

        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        if (response.StatusCode != FtpStatusCode.ClosingData)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine("Request {0}: Error uploading file to FTP server: {1} ({2})", Id, response.StatusDescription, response.StatusCode);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Request {0}: Successfully transferred file to {1}", Id, Output.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Same thing is here in your code it writes file while `bytesRead != 0`.
When ever `bytesRead = 0` it leaves the loop and stops the transfer.And shows Successfully transferred.