# How to Upload file to server using FTP

Tags: c#, .net, windows, c#-4.0

I have created a new window form application in C#. i want to upload a large file.

- And also i want to clarify the how to upload large file (e.g. 100 MB image)

Comment: You can use the BlobStorage of microsoft windows azure to store image / video / audio files which has size 100 mb or more..

Comment: As @lord_alek1 pointed out, see: [Upload large file to ftp C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19591067/upload-large-file-to-ftp-c-sharp) and [How to: Upload Files with FTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code example demonstrates using asynchronous operations to upload a file to an FTP server.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;

using System.IO;
namespace Examples.System.Net
{
    public class FtpState
    {
        private ManualResetEvent wait;
        private FtpWebRequest request;
        private string fileName;
        private Exception operationException = null;
        string status;

        public FtpState()
        {
            wait = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        }

        public ManualResetEvent OperationComplete
        {
            get {return wait;}
        }

        public FtpWebRequest Request
        {
            get {return request;}
            set {request = value;}
        }

        public string FileName
        {
            get {return fileName;}
            set {fileName = value;}
        }
        public Exception OperationException
        {
            get {return operationException;}
            set {operationException = value;}
        }
        public string StatusDescription
        {
            get {return status;}
            set {status = value;}
        }
    }
    public class AsynchronousFtpUpLoader
    {  
        // Command line arguments are two strings: 
        // 1. The url that is the name of the file being uploaded to the server. 
        // 2. The name of the file on the local machine. 
        // 
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create a Uri instance with the specified URI string. 
            // If the URI is not correctly formed, the Uri constructor 
            // will throw an exception.
            ManualResetEvent waitObject;

            Uri target = new Uri (args[0]);
            string fileName = args[1];
            FtpState state = new FtpState();
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(target);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

            // This example uses anonymous logon. 
            // The request is anonymous by default; the credential does not have to be specified.  
            // The example specifies the credential only to 
            // control how actions are logged on the server.

            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("anonymous","janeDoe@contoso.com");

            // Store the request in the object that we pass into the 
            // asynchronous operations.
            state.Request = request;
            state.FileName = fileName;

            // Get the event to wait on.
            waitObject = state.OperationComplete;

            // Asynchronously get the stream for the file contents.
            request.BeginGetRequestStream(
                new AsyncCallback (EndGetStreamCallback), 
                state
            );

            // Block the current thread until all operations are complete.
            waitObject.WaitOne();

            // The operations either completed or threw an exception. 
            if (state.OperationException != null)
            {
                throw state.OperationException;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The operation completed - {0}", state.StatusDescription);
            }
        }
        private static void EndGetStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            FtpState state = (FtpState) ar.AsyncState;

            Stream requestStream = null;
            // End the asynchronous call to get the request stream. 
            try
            {
                requestStream = state.Request.EndGetRequestStream(ar);
                // Copy the file contents to the request stream. 
                const int bufferLength = 2048;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLength];
                int count = 0;
                int readBytes = 0;
                FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(state.FileName);
                do
                {
                    readBytes = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                    requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
                    count += readBytes;
                }
                while (readBytes != 0);
                Console.WriteLine ("Writing {0} bytes to the stream.", count);
                // IMPORTANT: Close the request stream before sending the request.
                requestStream.Close();
                // Asynchronously get the response to the upload request.
                state.Request.BeginGetResponse(
                    new AsyncCallback (EndGetResponseCallback), 
                    state
                );
            } 
            // Return exceptions to the main application thread. 
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Could not get the request stream.");
                state.OperationException = e;
                state.OperationComplete.Set();
                return;
            }

        }

        // The EndGetResponseCallback method   
        // completes a call to BeginGetResponse. 
        private static void EndGetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            FtpState state = (FtpState) ar.AsyncState;
            FtpWebResponse response = null;
            try 
            {
                response = (FtpWebResponse) state.Request.EndGetResponse(ar);
                response.Close();
                state.StatusDescription = response.StatusDescription;
                // Signal the main application thread that  
                // the operation is complete.
                state.OperationComplete.Set();
            }
            // Return exceptions to the main application thread. 
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine ("Error getting response.");
                state.OperationException = e;
                state.OperationComplete.Set();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OK plz mark it as answer for your question to close it :))))

Comment: This is more or less the example from msdn. IMHO, though, it's not truly asynchronouns: as we can see, there is a `do while` loop which _synchronously_ writes into the request stream. This loop finishes only when all data has been written into the request stream. So, it has to block until after the data has been sent over the wire.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`FtpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx): the third example shows how to perform an upload.

(There is no real difference on the size of the file, other than more opportunities for a network issue to interrupt it.)